# Load external javascript on page load

Tags: javascript, html

In the footer of my site I want to show a map from [MarineTraffic](https://www.marinetraffic.com) Since the map loads a huge number of boat icons, locating there position, it slows the page load, even on my local machine. The code is put just before the closing body-tag.

The code needed to load the map can be scaled by adding a set of variables:

```
<script> 
width='100%';   // the width of the embedded map in pixels or percentage 
height='300';   // the height of the embedded map in pixels or percentage 
border='1'; // the width of the border around the map (zero means no border) 
shownames='true';   // to display ship names on the map (true or false) 
latitude='51.7143'; // the latitude of the center of the map, in decimal degrees 
longitude='04.0889';    // the longitude of the center of the map, in decimal degrees 
zoom='11';  // the zoom level of the map (values between 2 and 17) 
maptype='0';    // use 0 for Normal Map, 1 for Satellite, 2 for OpenStreetMap 
trackvessel='' //244770624';     MMSI of a vessel (note: vessel will be displayed only if within range of the system) - overrides "zoom" option 
fleet='';   // the registered email address of a user-defined fleet (user's default fleet is used) 
Read more at http://www.marinetraffic.com/en/p/embed-map#6YXCVvOUaBxYHgoT.99
</script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.marinetraffic.com/js/embed.js"></script>
```

The overcome the finding of the page load, I came up the idea of loading the scripts when the page is loaded. Already tried async or defer, however that messes up the functionality.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
var element = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "http://www.marinetraffic.com/js/embed.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
}
if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

I'm not that familiar with Javascript to figure out why the embed.js script doesn't load. (it should load without the variables too).

Someone willing to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have this onload script to load embed.js in head? This might be the problem because when the script loads there is no any body element. Keep your script before body ends.

Or you can try:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(element);
```

Anyways defer and async will do the same.

**EDIT:**

On your footer or just before closing body tag you can wait for the page load and execute this simple function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function() {

    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = 'http://www.marinetraffic.com/js/embed.js';

    document.body.appendChild(tag);

    }

 </script>
```

I don't know why async or defer is not working for you? Maybe it's working? You can always check when the line of code is being executed. You can use `onload` attribute to `console.log` or `alert` something in your script tag to check when the resource was loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The script is meant to load before the closing body-tag, and also positioned there. I’ll give your suggestion a try.

Comment: Tried Ashish suggestion, but no luck. No errors either.

Comment: So all I can guess the reason behind this is you are trying async way where the document first loads completely and you can't write anything to the document later.

Comment: Hmmm, that’s something I can’t solve. Would there be another way to achieve the same functionality?

Comment: Check my answer. I have edited with more information. Hope it helps.

Comment: Tried the script, but it shows a } on the front end. Been searching if there is a syntax error or so, but couldn't find snippet loading a script this way to check. If I only use <script defer type=".........</script>, than I get a warning in Firefox developer: **A call to document.write() from an asynchronously-loaded external script was ignored.** The error is pointing to the embed script line 28:2 Here it says: `document.write(`

Comment: `window.onload = function() {

    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = 'http://www.marinetraffic.com/js/embed.js';

    document.body.appendChild(tag);

    }`

This old way worked for me and my bad I forgot to comment the tag in previous edit.

Comment: I get warning though but the script seems fine.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I do see the js-file directly above the body-tag, but it doesn't load. Same warning. In the network tab from Firefox I noticed the file is cached and 0bytes are send. Clearing the cache etc. doesn't help. Are there any other options to achieve similar behavior?

Comment: I am not so good at JavaScript but will definitely find new solution and update the answer.